# How to fetch the records of last 24 hours or 7 days from today's date using Joda-Time API

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying out my hand in finding out records which have been updated in the Oracle 11g DB in last 24 hours or 7 days or 30 days. I am able to get the desired functionality using "java.util.Calendar"

```
Date today = new Date();

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(today);
//For last 7 days
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
```

however I am wondering if anyone has done this with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define *exactly* what you mean by "last 24 hours" and "last 7 days". Do you *really* mean the last 24 hours, or "since the same local time yesterday"? The latter could mean 23 hours or 25 hours, due to daylight saving transitions.

If you really, really want exactly 24 hours and exactly 7 * 24 hours, I would use `Instant`:

```
Instant now = new Instant();
Instant nowMinus24Hours = now.plus(Durations.standardHours(-24));
Instant nowMinus7Days = now.plus(Durations.standardDays(-7));
```

Note that `Instant` has no concept of a time zone or calendar - it's *just* a point on the timeline; it's an appropriate data type to use for timestamps and the like.